# Webcam light doesnt turn off after setting the video constraint to false in webRtc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, mediastream

I am using WebRTC and socket.io for video calling.

The call is working fine but when I run the turn off camera function, the video stops but the light of my webcam remains on.

Here is the function for turning off the camera:

```
const mute = () => {
  setMuteCamera(true);
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true })
    .then((stream) => {
      setStream(stream);
      myVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
      if (stream != null) {
        stream?.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
          track.stop();
        });
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` a **new** *MediaStream* is created, with **new** *MediaStreamTracks*. Closing these new *MediaStreamTracks* won't close the previous ones.

So what you need is to keep track of your previous *MediaStream*, and close the VideoTrack from it.
Given your current code it seems that you do set it as `myVideo.current.srcObject`, if so, you can access it from there:

```js
const muteVideoTrack = () => {
  myVideo.current.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
};
```

Or you could also simply store this *MediaStream* in any variable accessible to your method.
This will let the *MediaStream* capture only the microphone. If you wanted to completely stop the whole MediaStream, then call `getTracks()` instead of `getVideoTracks()`, and optionally set the `srcObject` to `null`.

Comment: Is there a way to start the same media stream that is stopped. I have found that there is no method like track.start()

Comment: I have tried this approach and it does not work. Why on earth is this so complicated?

Comment: @zero_cool without seeing your code we can't help you. Feel free to open a new question with a proper [mre], and which explain what you've tried and how it failed.

Comment: It's literally the same exact thing. Just curious if any one has found a solution that works.

Comment: @zero_cool well this answer worked for OP. You certainly are missing something. Please post a new question with your code in a way we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @zero_cool: My experience is that the works fine except in Safari. Maybe that's the issue?